# How do I make a 2D list of TextBoxes?

Tags: c#, list

```
private List<TextBox>[,] textBoxesList = new List<TextBox>[6,3]; // would be my list soon
private TextBox[,] textBoxes = new TextBox[6,3]; // my array of text boxes

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int j = 0; j < textBoxes.Length(0); j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < textBoxesList.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            textBoxes[j,i] = new TextBox();
            textBoxes[j,i].Size = new Size(35, 20);
            textBoxes[j,i].Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            textBoxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90 + j * 50, 50 + i * 30);

            textBoxes[j,i].Parent = this;
            this.Controls.Add(textBoxes[j,i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So this is how I've done it with an array. Now I'm very inexperienced at lists. In fact I never learned lists before but have briefly heard that they can grow/shrink compared to arrays. It would be useful for me to use lists so the user can add a row later on.

---

Tested this code but it's showing blank.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //List<List<TextBox>> li = new List<List<TextBox>>();  
    List<TextBox> litxt = new List<TextBox>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Size = new Size(35, 20);
        litxt.Add(txt);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            litxt.Add(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GrantWinney This is for making a table, where the user can add in an extra row. Kinda like an excel except it's in a Windows Form.

Comment: Have you considered the DataGridView control? This seems to suit your purposes better.

Comment: @StevieB Never used it but I might try it. pretty much I don't know most controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2D list do it like this

```
List<List<TextBox>> li = new List<List<TextBox>>();
```

As you need to make a table of text box use a `FlowLayoutPanel` of fixed width equal to 3 textboxes

Make a list

```
List<TextBox> litxt = new List<TextBox>();
```

Add 3 Text box to litxt

```
for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
{
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.Size = new Size(35,20);
litxt.Add(txt);
}
```

Put this Code on the condition where you want to add 3 TextBox

```
foreach(TextBox txt in litxt)
{
FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

[image: What it should look like]

### Put This Code

**Add a flowlayout panel to your form and perform this code**

```
        public Rough()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Rough_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        static int i = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < 3 ; i++,j++)
           {
               TextBox txt = new TextBox();
               txt.Size = new Size(35, 20);
               txt.Name = i.ToString();
               flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txt);
            }   
        }
```

Comment: What about the length? I renamed it to `textBoxList` but it's not working for the length.

Comment: As your question Says you need a 2D list of TextBoxes but i did'nt Understand what your description trying to say make it more clear

Comment: The reason I use a 2D list is because I'm making a table of textboxes. The point of the list is so the user can add an extra row and it would add in like 3 more text boxes basically.

Comment: @GrantWinney I'm stuck at the length part. How do I get the length of the list that I got?

Comment: use the way i had suggested

Comment: Uhm I tested a part of the code, but it's not really working. It will run but it doesn't show anything on the screen. Also, made a LayoutPanel

Comment: It doesn't really seem to work still. I didn't use the 3rd piece of code you gave me because it gave me an error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls.get'` It didn't display. Btw, without the add, what does it display? It doesn't seem to display anything on the screen.

Comment: wait il give you exact solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic `Dictionary` and make your own key struct to access the elements.

The key struct `MyKey`:

```
public struct MyKey
{
    private ushort row;
    private ushort col;

    public int Row { get { return row; } }
    public int Col { get { return col; } }

    public MyKey(int row, int col)
    {
        // check if keys are in range between 0 and ushort.MaxValue
        if(row < 0 || row > ushort.MaxValue || col < 0 || col > ushort.MaxValue)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("Arguments row and col cannot be less than 0 or greater than {0}.", ushort.MaxValue));
        this.row = (ushort) row;
        this.col = (ushort) col;
    }

    // Overriden GetHashCode() that's used by the Dictionary to search through the keys.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // we just shift Row by 16 Bits to left and make a bitwise or with Col to generate the Hashcode
        return ((int) row << 16) | col;
    }
}
```

And now you can use this key with `Dictionary`:

```
var textBoxesList = new Dictionary<MyKey, TextBox>();
var rowCount = 6;
var colCount = 3;

for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
    {
        var key = new MyKey(row, col);
        var textBox = new TextBox();

        textBox.Size = new Size(35, 20);
        textBox.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90 + row * 50, 50 + col * 30);
        textBox.Parent = this;

        // store the key in the Tag property of the TextBox
        // so you can get the row and the column of your textbox with
        // var key = (MyKey) textBox.Tag
        textBox.Tag = key; 

        textBoxesList.Add(key, textBox);

        this.Controls.Add(textBox);
    }
}
```

If you want to get a TextBox by row 2 and column 4 you can write:

```
var textbox = textBoxesList[new MyKey(row: 2, col: 4)];
```

You can also walk though the collection:

```
foreach (var item in textBoxesList)
{
    var row = item.Key.Row;
    var col = item.Key.Col;
    var textbox = item.Value;
    // ...
}
```

And for example you can search the `textBoxesList` for TextBoxes in a specific row. Let's say we wanna get all Textboxes in row 2 ordered by the column number:

```
var textBoxesInRow2 = (from item in textBoxesList
                        where item.Key.Row == 2
                        orderby item.Key.Col
                        select item.Value)
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
List<List<TextBoxes>>
```

and

You could use a `TextBox[,]` for this purpose:

```
private TextBox[,] textboxes;

public YourClass() {
    // Add this after the text boxes have actually been set up...

    textboxes = new TextBox[,] {
        {textbox00, textbox01, textbox02, ...},
        {textbox10, textbox11, textbox12, ...},
        ,,,
    };
}
```

Then you can access `textbox00` as `textboxes[0,0]`, `textbox56` as `textboxes[5,6]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each row has the same number of checkboxes (e.g. 3) then you could do it like this:

```
List<TextBox[3]> textboxes = new List<TextBox[3]>
{
    new TextBox[3] { textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 };
    new TextBox[3] { textbox4, textbox5, textbox6 };
};
```

Then when you want to add a new row of checkboxes

```
textboxes.Add(new TextBox[3] { textbox7, textbox8, textbox9 }; );
```

Note: The DataGridView control may be a better option than TextBoxes for you.
It gives you that Excel like cell structure and you can easily wire a `List` to it as the data source.